# Want my data to be fixed on button click - php

Tags: javascript, php, html

My html page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Vikram</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="developer" content="Sanmitha V S" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/showtimes.css" />
        <script src="../js/showtimes.js"></script>
        
    </head>

    <body>
    
            <form action="../php/action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
        <nav>
        <h2 class="h1" name="h2">Vikram</h2>
        <img src="../img/movie1.jpg" alt="vikram_movie" id="vikram" />
    
            <h2>Showtimes : </h2> 
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> 12:00 </a></li>
            <li><a href="movie1_s2.html"> 15:30 </a></li>
            <li><a href="movie1_s3.html"> 19:00 </a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Book Tickets</button>
            <br><br>
            <a href="../index.html">Back to Home Page</a>
        </nav>
        
        <div id="left">
        
        <header>
            <h1 class="h1">Jazz Film City </h1>
        </header>
        
            
            <label for="no_seats">No. of seats </label>
                <select id="no_seats"  name="no_seats">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                </select>
            
                <label for="selected">Selected slot</label>
                <input type="text" id="st" name="st" value="12:00" size=5 readonly />
                
                <label for="selected">Selected seats</label>
                <textarea id="selected" name="selected" readonly></textarea>
                <br><br>
        
        <div id="seat_ar">
        <br>
            Platinum section : Rs. 220<br><br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a1" onclick="select(a1)" alt="a1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a2" onclick="select(a2)" alt="a2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a3" onclick="select(a3)" alt="a3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a4" onclick="select(a4)" alt="a4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a5" onclick="select(a5)" alt="a5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a6" onclick="select(a6)" alt="a6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a7" onclick="select(a7)" alt="a7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a8" onclick="select(a8)" alt="a8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a9" onclick="select(a9)" alt="a9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a10" onclick="select(a10)" alt="a10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a11" onclick="select(a11)" alt="a11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a12" onclick="select(a12)" alt="a12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a13" onclick="select(a13)" alt="a13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a14" onclick="select(a14)" alt="a14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="a15" onclick="select(a15)" alt="a15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b1" onclick="select(b1)" alt="b1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b2" onclick="select(b2)" alt="b2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b3" onclick="select(b3)" alt="b3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b4" onclick="select(b4)" alt="b4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b5" onclick="select(b5)" alt="b5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b6" onclick="select(b6)" alt="b6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b7" onclick="select(b7)" alt="b7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b8" onclick="select(b8)" alt="b8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b9" onclick="select(b9)" alt="b9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b10" onclick="select(b10)" alt="b10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b11" onclick="select(b11)" alt="b11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b12" onclick="select(b12)" alt="b12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b13" onclick="select(b13)" alt="b13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b14" onclick="select(b14)" alt="b14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="b15" onclick="select(b15)" alt="b15" class="seats">
            <br>
            Gold section : Rs. 180<br><br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c1" onclick="select(c1)" alt="c1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c2" onclick="select(c2)" alt="c2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c3" onclick="select(c3)" alt="c3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c4" onclick="select(c4)" alt="c4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c5" onclick="select(c5)" alt="c5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c6" onclick="select(c6)" alt="c6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c7" onclick="select(c7)" alt="c7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c8" onclick="select(c8)" alt="c8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c9" onclick="select(c9)" alt="c9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c10" onclick="select(c10)" alt="c10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c11" onclick="select(c11)" alt="c11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c12" onclick="select(c12)" alt="c12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c13" onclick="select(c13)" alt="c13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c14" onclick="select(c14)" alt="c14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="c15" onclick="select(c15)" alt="c15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d1" onclick="select(d1)" alt="d1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d2" onclick="select(d2)" alt="d2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d3" onclick="select(d3)" alt="d3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d4" onclick="select(d4)" alt="d4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d5" onclick="select(d5)" alt="d5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d6" onclick="select(d6)" alt="d6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d7" onclick="select(d7)" alt="d7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d8" onclick="select(d8)" alt="d8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d9" onclick="select(d9)" alt="d9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d10" onclick="select(d10)" alt="d10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d11" onclick="select(d11)" alt="d11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d12" onclick="select(d12)" alt="d12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d13" onclick="select(d13)" alt="d13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d14" onclick="select(d14)" alt="d14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="d15" onclick="select(d15)" alt="d15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e1" onclick="select(e1)" alt="e1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e2" onclick="select(e2)" alt="e2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e3" onclick="select(e3)" alt="e3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e4" onclick="select(e4)" alt="e4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e5" onclick="select(e5)" alt="e5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e6" onclick="select(e6)" alt="e6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e7" onclick="select(e7)" alt="e7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e8" onclick="select(e8)" alt="e8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e9" onclick="select(e9)" alt="e9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e10" onclick="select(e10)" alt="e10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e11" onclick="select(e11)" alt="e11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e12" onclick="select(e12)" alt="e12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e13" onclick="select(e13)" alt="e13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e14" onclick="select(e14)" alt="e14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="e15" onclick="select(e15)" alt="e15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f1" onclick="select(f1)" alt="f1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f2" onclick="select(f2)" alt="f2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f3" onclick="select(f3)" alt="f3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f4" onclick="select(f4)" alt="f4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f5" onclick="select(f5)" alt="f5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f6" onclick="select(f6)" alt="f6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f7" onclick="select(f7)" alt="f7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f8" onclick="select(f8)" alt="f8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f9" onclick="select(f9)" alt="f9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f10" onclick="select(f10)" alt="f10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f11" onclick="select(f11)" alt="f11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f12" onclick="select(f12)" alt="f12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f13" onclick="select(f13)" alt="f13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f14" onclick="select(f14)" alt="f14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="f15" onclick="select(f15)" alt="f15" class="seats">
            <br>
            Silver section : Rs. 100<br><br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g1" onclick="select(g1)" alt="g1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g2" onclick="select(g2)" alt="g2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g3" onclick="select(g3)" alt="g3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g4" onclick="select(g4)" alt="g4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g5" onclick="select(g5)" alt="g5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g6" onclick="select(g6)" alt="g6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g7" onclick="select(g7)" alt="g7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g8" onclick="select(g8)" alt="g8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g9" onclick="select(g9)" alt="g9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g10" onclick="select(g10)" alt="g10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g11" onclick="select(g11)" alt="g11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g12" onclick="select(g12)" alt="g12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g13" onclick="select(g13)" alt="g13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g14" onclick="select(g14)" alt="g14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="g15" onclick="select(g15)" alt="g15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h1" onclick="select(h1)" alt="h1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h2" onclick="select(h2)" alt="h2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h3" onclick="select(h3)" alt="h3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h4" onclick="select(h4)" alt="h4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h5" onclick="select(h5)" alt="h5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h6" onclick="select(h6)" alt="h6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h7" onclick="select(h7)" alt="h7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h8" onclick="select(h8)" alt="h8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h9" onclick="select(h9)" alt="h9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h10" onclick="select(h10)" alt="h10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h11" onclick="select(h11)" alt="h11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h12" onclick="select(h12)" alt="h12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h13" onclick="select(h13)" alt="h13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h14" onclick="select(h14)" alt="h14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="h15" onclick="select(h15)" alt="h15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i1" onclick="select(i1)" alt="i1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i2" onclick="select(i2)" alt="i2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i3" onclick="select(i3)" alt="i3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i4" onclick="select(i4)" alt="i4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i5" onclick="select(i5)" alt="i5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i6" onclick="select(i6)" alt="i6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i7" onclick="select(i7)" alt="i7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i8" onclick="select(i8)" alt="i8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i9" onclick="select(i9)" alt="i9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i10" onclick="select(i10)" alt="i10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i11" onclick="select(i11)" alt="i11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i12" onclick="select(i12)" alt="i12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i13" onclick="select(i13)" alt="i13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i14" onclick="select(i14)" alt="i14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="i15" onclick="select(i15)" alt="i15" class="seats">
            <br>
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j1" onclick="select(j1)" alt="j1" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j2" onclick="select(j2)" alt="j2" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j3" onclick="select(j3)" alt="j3" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j4" onclick="select(j4)" alt="j4" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j5" onclick="select(j5)" alt="j5" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j6" onclick="select(j6)" alt="j6" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j7" onclick="select(j7)" alt="j7" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j8" onclick="select(j8)" alt="j8" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j9" onclick="select(j9)" alt="j9" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j10" onclick="select(j10)" alt="j10" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j11" onclick="select(j11)" alt="j11" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j12" onclick="select(j12)" alt="j12" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j13" onclick="select(j13)" alt="j13" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j14" onclick="select(j14)" alt="j14" class="seats">
            <img src="../img/vaccant.jpg" id="j15" onclick="select(j15)" alt="j15" class="seats">
            <br><br><br>
            <img src="../img/screen_this_way.png" alt="Screen this way" id="stw" />
        </div>
        </div>
        
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js file :

```
var i=1;
var res=new Array();
function select(seat){
    n=document.getElementById("no_seats");
    n1=parseInt(n.options[n.selectedIndex].text);
    if((seat.getAttribute("src")=="../img/vaccant.jpg") &&(i<=n1)){
        seat.src="../img/select.jpg";
            i++;
            res.push(seat.alt);
    }
    else if(seat.getAttribute("src")=="../img/select.jpg"){
        seat.src="../img/vaccant.jpg";
            i--;
            for(j in res){
            if(res[j]==seat.alt)
                res.splice(j,1);
        }
        
    }
    document.getElementById("selected").value=res;
}

function check(){
    var n =document.getElementById("selected").value;
    if(n.length ==0){
        alert("Please select your seats");
        return false;
    }
}
```

My php file :

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Personal details</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="developer" content="Sanmitha V S" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/action.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Your details : </h1>
        </header>
        
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Details</legend>
            
            <label for="firstName">First Name : </label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Your first name" required />
            
            <label for="lastName">Last Name : </label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Your last name" required />
            <br><br>
            
            <label for="email">Email id:  </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="Your email id" required />
        
            <label for="phone">Phone:  </label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"  placeholder="Your phone number" pattern="[0-9]{5} [0-9]{5}" required />
            <br>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Slot and seating </legend>
            <?php
            $s=$_POST["selected"];
            $a=explode(',',$s);
            if((count($a)==1) && ($a[0]=="")){
                unset($a[0]);
            }
            $n=count($a);
            echo "Selected slot : ".$_POST["st"]."<br><br>";
            echo "Number of seats : ".$n."<br><br>";
            echo "Selected seats : ".$_POST["selected"]."<br><br>";
            $p=array();
            foreach($a as $i){
                switch($i[0])
                {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'b':
                        array_push($p,220);
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                    case 'd':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'f':
                        array_push($p,180);
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                    case 'h':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'j':
                        array_push($p,100);
                        break;
                }
            }
            ?>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Total Amount to be payed</legend>
            
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Seat</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody>
            <?php
            for($i=0;$i<count($p);$i++){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$a[$i]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$p[$i]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            
                $sum=array_sum($p);
                $gst=(15*$sum)/100;
                echo "Total Amount to be payed : ".($sum+$gst)."<br>";
                echo " Ticket amount : ".$sum."<br>";
                echo "%12 gst : ".$gst;
                
            ?>
            <button name="go_pay" id="go_pay">Go to Payment</button>
            <?php
            
                if (isset($_POST['go_pay'])){
                $fn=$_POST["firstName"];
                $ln=$_POST["lastName"];
                $_SESSION[$fn." ".$ln]=array($a, $sum+$gst);
                print_r($_SESSION[$fn." ".$ln]);
                }
                ?>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
        
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The js file and php file are perfectly linked with the html file.
When I click the button `Go to payment`, the data stored in the html page gets erased. Whereas I want my data to stay there when I click the button. I tried various methods but I couldn't achieve the desired results. I used various arrays, sessions to accomplish but it ended in vain. Is there any simple way to accomplish the task ? Please help !

Comment: the above `My php file :` has the HTML declaration **before** `session_start()` and then after too. Remove the 1st instance - there should be **no** HTML output before the `session_start()`

Comment: Please try to clarify the problem - it is not obvious what you mean precisely. If you POST to the PHP script using AJAX the page would stay the same until you manipulate it in the callback otherwise a regular form submission ( as here ) will cause the page to reload by default so perhaps you need to assign the POST variable to each form element as it's value ?

Comment: I want the textarea value, select, values to be retained when I click the button

Comment: but not the individual text input values?

Comment: to retain Every input value

Comment: ok - in which PHP page - surely it can only be `My html page :` (ie: the 1st script)?

Comment: You can't submit the form in the regular manner to another page and retain the form values.... that makes no sense. The form is submitted to `../php/action.php` (presumably this is the last script shown above?) but that script/page does not have the same inputs/ form elements.

Comment: Any alternate way to do so?

Comment: Post to the same page and have a function that re-populates the POSTed data as values for the various form input elements or use AJAX and update the DOM with the callback.